# Stopping overlap for bigger words

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game at the moment, the grid is designed for 3 letter words. I can add bigger words into the "wordList" (which creates the grid dynamically), but the size of the grid changes and overlaps on the rows where the bigger words are.

At the moment when a four letter word is added for example, the grid will add an extra cell to the end of that row rather than judging that the word will not fit on that line and take another position in the grid that works.

Basically I need the grid to stay the same size, and when words are randomly placed, determine a position that allows the grid to stay 6x6 rather than going out the edges when they do not fit in position. Obviously when words bigger than 6 letters are added this will not work, because it is a 6x6, but this shouldn't be a problem as I do not think we will stretch to words that big.

Words are added through the html like this...

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">
    <li data-word="rat" 
        data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav" 
        data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/j/X/e/k/D/mouse-md.png">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the grid is dynamically created from the list like this...

```
var listOfWords = [];
var rndWord = [];
var counter = 0;
var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i) {

    listOfWords.push({
        "name": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
     });
}

var chosenWords = [];
var copylist = listOfWords.slice();

for (var x = 0; x < ul.children.length; x++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (copylist.length));
    chosenWords.push(copylist[rand].name);
    copylist.splice(rand, 1);
    if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
        chosenWords.push('   ');
    }

}

var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

var guesses = {};
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop-box').attr('data-word', word).attr('data-letter', word[k]);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
         }
    }

    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

$(".container").append(tbl);
```

Here is a fiddle to show exactly what I mean. I have added two 4 letter words into the "wordList" to show what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/cTGGA/18/

EDIT

Once I have adapted larger words into the grid what will I say in this statement to prepare it.

```
var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var completeWords = (completeLetters / 3);
$('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you either need to make the word selection from the shuffledword list a function that returns the next unused word that fits the space remaining in the row.

or have the rows be 2x the longest word if you want 2 words per row and fill with blanks to the end of the row after picking one or 2 words from the list.

Comment: The first option sounds like the better option to be honest. I have it set to 2 words per row already you see. Could you point me in the right direction? @claya

Comment: I introduced underscore.js to the fiddle. It's a useful utility for managing lists see http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/ I think you'll like it. 
I forked your original jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tirams/Dxxmh

Comment: Thank you so much I will have a look at that. Will it support any size words up to 6? and if I make the grid bigger will it support even bigger words? @claya

Comment: I don't suppose you could show me what I would do with this now that the letter size varies? Check edit @claya

Comment: So now there are just 2 variables numLetters and numRows which are the dimensions of your grid. If you want to add more rows increase the numRows var and add more words to your word list, if you want more letters per row in your grid increase the numLetters variable, and make all your word choices less than or equal to that value in length.

Comment: For some reason when I transfered the code into eclipse it has come up withy the weirdest error. Do you have any idea why? It has been since I added your piece of code ti it

Comment: hmm. did you include the underscore.js from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js into your project or html file?

Comment: I know it has been a while, but would there have been a jQuery alternative to the underscore.js you gave me? Thanks @claya

Comment: underscore.js is compatible with jQuery the url is http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js you can add it to your resources in jsfiddle or into your html <head> 

If you rather not use undercore.js you can replace the _.find calls with loops over the array on the first parameter to find and call the function thats the second find parameter to see if the item is found and create a new array of the matches as they are found.

Comment: info on underscore here http://internetwebsitedesign.biz/tutorials/getting-cozy-with-underscore-js